# Protractor don't wait for $http result

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm facing the following problem and I can't get rid of it :

1. I've got an Angular app that calls an API using `$http.post`,
2. this api call make an update to the database and wait 10 sec before returning,
3. on return of the call, a dialogue is open on the browser saying that test is terminated

When I try to test this small app with Protractor, the test ends before the step 3 occurs. This make my test fail because update in database is not always done. During the test, I see the dialogue opening after 10 sec.

Here is some code.
My Angular service doing the call :

```
$http.post(url, parameters).
        success(function (data) {
            $log.debug('Success in cldHttp data is "%s"', JSON.stringify(data));
            NotifSrv.translateMessage('commons.request.ok', [],
                function (successMessage) {
                    data.errorMessage = null;
                    if (options.notifySuccess) NotifSrv.addNotification(successMessage, 'success');
                    if (cb) cb(undefined, data);
                });
        });
```

My Protractor test :

```
browser.get('/#!/activate-account.html?id=' + acc._id).then(function () {
                browser.sleep(1000);
                // Check that DB is updated
                accountColl.findOne({
                    pseudo: 'MyActivatePseudo'
                }, function (err, acc2) {
                    expect(err).to.not.exist;                                // OK
                    expect(acc2.activated).to.be.true;                       // KO the DB update has been done just after the findOne
                });
            });
```

I try the `browser.sleep()` in the protractor test but it does nothing.

Many thank's for your help because I'm totally stuck!

JM.